# I don't understand why I get this valgrind error

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I got the following code:

```
/* main.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){
  int i;
  char *msg = "This is a simple and small message";
  int len = strlen (msg);
  char *new_msg = (char *) malloc (len);
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    new_msg[i] = 'A';
  printf ("%s\n", new_msg);
  free (new_msg);
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled it and then run it using valgrind with this command:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./main
```

I got the this output:

```
==8286== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8286== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8286== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8286== Command: ./main
==8286== 
==8286== Invalid read of size 1
==8286==    at 0x4C2C1B4: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:412)
==8286==    by 0x4EA09FB: puts (ioputs.c:36)
==8286==    by 0x400636: main (main.c:12)
==8286==  Address 0x51de062 is 0 bytes after a block of size 34 alloc'd
==8286==    at 0x4C28C20: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:296)
==8286==    by 0x400601: main (main.c:9)
==8286== 
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
==8286== 
==8286== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8286==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8286==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 34 bytes allocated
==8286== 
==8286== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8286== 
==8286== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8286== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I see that all the allocated memory was released, but I still get an error that I don't understand.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a pretty straightforward error: there is an invalid read of `new_msg` because the null terminator is not there.

You have allocated the number of `char`s equal to the length of the original string, so currently there's no space to fit `'\0'` without making undefined behavior. Change your code as follows to fix the problem:

```
char *new_msg = malloc (len+1);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    new_msg[i] = 'A';
new_msg[len] = '\0';
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the explanation. Now it works. Secondly, I saw that you removed the cast of the malloc. Why is that? I run it with and without the cast and still got the same output (even on valgrind). Is there any difference?

Comment: @mikmik [Here is a good Q&A on casting `malloc` results](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/335858). The idea behind not casting is that you have specified the type already, so you are repeating the same piece of code again. A cast could also hide subtle errors.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things to be changes in your code.

1) `len` should be of `size_t` not `int`, as `strlen()` returns of type `size_t`

2) `(char *) malloc (len);` drop the cast. This isn't an error, although there are reasons one should not cast.

3) `new_msg` is not NULL terminated `\0`. This is the reason the error is occurring.

Comment: Numbers 1 and 2 are not reason for this issue. It's OK to mention them, but please make the distinction clear.

Comment: @Haris The cast is not an error but very useful  information on the one hand and allows to prevent iincorrect assignment. on the other hand

Answer (score 0):

you use `strlen()` to get length, but not contain the '\0'.
so when you malloc a new array, you should use `len + 1`, and set `new_msg[len]` is `'\0'`.